# Robot Creation and Copyrights

Tags: creature-design, society, robots, far-future, future

Let's say that in the year 2200 you can design and create your own android much like those ones of the game Detroit Become Human but instead of going to a store you customize and buy them using advanced 3d printing and molecular nanotechnology.And a solitary person who wanted a partner but is shy and has a lot of trouble dating wants to create his own android and then he creates a robot who looks like an attractive model with personalized physical and mental features.

If this person sucessfully creates this robot should they apply copyrights on it in order to avoid other people with similar tastes from creating the same robot model? Why or why not? Since robots are designed and created like an artwork or a building would they need copyrights in order for them to have a unique design for each android much like a human being? No two humans look identical apart from clones and twins.

Comment: This is unanswerable since we do not know what legislation may exist in 2200 in whatever jurisdiction this may occur in.  If a jurisdiction were specified and the object being created was a 3D model or doll then this could be asked on Law SE to get an answer based on the laws that exist today.  I would suggest removing the names of particular models and describing particular features, however (here and on Law SE) as they are not relevant to the question.

Comment: I would say that copyrighting it will be beneficial, whatever it is. Because you can then license your design and get some sweet-sweet money. But like anything, it depends.

Comment: definitely get a copyright! someone may steal your design to sell and alleged you are the thief...  you may win the lawsuit but spare yourselves the trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure prevention should be an issue unless that 's a part of the story - it sounds like a potential revenue stream if they hold the original copyright.

Comment: One cannot "apply copyrights" on anything. The creator of a work automatically holds the copyright on that work as soon as the work is fixed in a tangible medium. Please note that a machine (or any item which has a practical, utilitary function) is not considered a work for the purpose of copyright; the appearance of a machine can be protected by a design patent / registered design, but this protection must be actively applied for. (Unlike copyright, which is automatic.) (The likeness of a human is protected by privacy laws and personality laws, which have nothing to do with copyright.)

Comment: I doubt a tuned-down-to-reality question with no robot on Law.SE would be useful enough (it's a bit too sci-fi and out of real-life scope). However, you do need to tell at least which law book/country you use/your character is, telling important differences which have come over time (e.g. : robots considered alive like pets? Copyright destroyed for trademarks/patents only?...)

Comment: Destroy copyright, we don't need it.

Comment: Even if the alterate world retains automatic copyright, proving a violation is easier if a copy of the coprighted work is registered. It's much cheaper and easier than a patent.  Speaking of patents, he's customizing a shell, not patenting the robots mechanisms. Ford owns the design patents on the F150 pickup truck, but if I decorate mine in a unique way, I own the copyright on the art I created. I can put the same artwork on a different vehicle, but if anyone else does, I could drag them into court.

Answer (score 1):

In our world:

If one person creates their own android design from scratch, then if another person also creates from scratch a design indistinguishable from the first, then it wouldn't be a breach of copyright, since each design is the creator's own work, and may in fact differ in subtle ways not apparent from a cursory examination.

On the other hand, using a pre-made design without the author's permission would likely be a breach of intellectual property laws, even if it was 'tweaked', as it would still substantially be the first person's work.

In the OP's world (possibly):

However, since this is the OP's world, the IP laws may differ, and be applied to the form of the work, rather than the effort put into creating it.

If IP laws protect end-products rather than effort, then use of a celebrity's likeness without permission would probably be a breach of IP laws, unless it can be shown that the creator of the likeness had no knowledge of the celebrity whose likeness' IP was infringed at the time that likeness was created.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, but I sometimes play one on tthe internet.

First advice: Don't make your robot's face or body too close to any real person (or anyone else's artwork), especially if that person has a legal team. Curvy is fine. Close copies of a specific set of curves is a recipe for legal issues.

If you paint a picture, you own the copyright.
If you sculpt a statue, you own the copyright.
If your sculpture happens to be a robot, you would still own the copyright.

But beware of the TOS if you use an outside service.

DreamBots design software may have terms allowing them to sell copies of your design.
YourSpecialFriend robot factory may also have terms granting them rights to sell copies of what you ask them to build.

If you do avoid sharing rights to your design and also want to sell copies to others, you could trademark any unique features as well as terms associated with your product.

Comment: As far as I know a machine (that, an article which has a practical, utilitary function) is not considered a sculpture for copyright purpose. The appearance of such a machine *can* be protected by a design patent (USA) / registered design (rest of the world), but, unlike copyright, such protection needs to be actively applied for.

Comment: @AlexP -Interesting point. As I see it, the machine isn't what he wants to protect. He doesn't care if people have their own fantasy robots. What he wants to protect is the unique elements of the face and specific body shape of his robot. I would see this like adding a kinetic ability to a statue or other artwork is still copyrighted as art, not patented practical device. For safety, he could also copyright images and a statue with exactly the same face and body. Then even if his copyright on the robot... shell(?) doesn't hold up, he would still have an IP claim on any identical looking robot.

Comment: And if anyone thinks the curves of a human body aren't copyrightable, think again. https://money.cnn.com/2015/04/26/technology/copyright-boobs-revenge-porn/index.html

Comment: (1) He can apply for a design patent (int the USA) or a registered design (elsewhere). There are important differences between those and copyright, but in the essence they both protect against unauthorized reproduction of the object. (2) The article makes it clear that she did not copyright her curves (which she cannot, for the obvious reason that they are not a creative work that she made), she registered a copyright on *photographs* of the curves of her body. Other, new, photographs would not be covered by the registered copyright.

Comment: @AlexP, She used new photos to do takedowns on old photos. That would imply that it is possible to copyright the shape of one's own anatomy. Along the same lines, if I decorate the outer body of my car, paint plus unique shape customizations that do not alter tha car's function (other than probably making it less aerodynamic), I'd say that's a copywritable artwork. I can't manufacture copies of the car (the carmaker owns or leases all the IP for that), but no one else can copy my customizations or make derivative ones. That seems like the goal the person asking the question wanted to achieve.

Comment: One *cannot* copyright anything. That's not how copyright works. When one creates a creative work and fixes it in a reproducible medium, the creator of the work (or, or and, their employer, as the case may be) *automatically* gets the copyright on the work. One may then proceed to *register* the copyright, but that is a purely administrative act, it does not create a new copyright. The likeness of a person is protected by other kinds of legal protections which have nothing to do with copyright. (And of course you own the copyright on your new original designs painted on a car.)

Comment: @AlexP - Sort of, but not quite. The woman with the online photo issue Registered a copyright on her breasts. Anyone can register a copyright on their work to make enforcement easier (similar to registering a trademark vs. just claiming one). If this were not true, this.page wouldn't exist: https://www.copyright.gov/registration/

Comment: @AlexP - By copyrightable, I mean my car exterior art qualifies for copyright protection as art, registered or not. Similarly, if GeneralBots sells me a bot I decorate (or pay them to decorate per my design) and no additional function is added, I firmly believe tgat exterior design I made would be my  IP overlaying the legitimslely purchased bot that has its own IP. Since it is art and not function, copyright (preferably registeredx would be the simplest choice to prevent anyone else from owning a bot (from any manufacturer or homemade) from copying my artistic customizations.

Answer (score 0):

### Mods

Instead of copywriting a face, maybe one could guarantee that they get an android with a unique face by modding the robot. I could see it like this: In this world, due to large android-making corporations, its made to be very difficult to copywrite an android's look (high cost, long beauricratic process...). So instead people buy an android with a typical face and then mod their android to have a unique face - this could also allow for more artistic representations of faces that you can't get from the manufacturer. Because few people do this it basically guarantees that the face you modded is unique. And it voids your warrantee xD.

This was a plot point in Ghost in the Shell Stand Alone Complex Season 2, about the villian. They got an artist to make a unique, beautiful face, however it was unable to emote.

### Potential Problems with Copywriting a face

Not a lawyer either, but the concept of copywriting a face might be difficult to swing - how do you define a face? What attributes would you use to define the face, and how would you describe it in a legal document?

Answer (score 0):

**Copyright on shape but not on function**

There are many companies making cars. Cars' body shapes are patented but functions are not. All cars have gears, lights, valves which may have slightly different shapes but they do the same thing.

Similarly, you can patent the shape of a robot but there is no copyright for the function it will perform.

Comment: Car shapes also may include patentable aerodynamics and even ergonomics of doors and windows. The basic shape of a human is far less variable than a car. The basic shape of a human can't be secured under IP laws. but copyright can cover the unique features in the shape of a statue of a human. If someone owns the IP on a generic statue and I legally purchase a copy and customize it, my customizations are copyright since what I did was art. If the statue as sold was robotic, I don't see that affecting the art I overlay it with.